# Alarm manager stops unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-widget, alarmmanager, android-service

I have created a clock widget with some nice backgrounds. I use Alarm Manager to update time and background every 1 minute. But it stops working after few hours, means I can run that widget, I also get time and background on screen respectively. But after some time(few hours) it stops updating time and background in widget. I have done following things,

OnUpdate method - set alarma manager that signals every 1 minute.
Called a service using pending intent in that alarm manager.
Used AsyncTask to change bitmap image (Otherwise I get ANR error) from service.
Used stopself to stop service after widget update is finished.

I used lots of try catch, at different places to get errors if any, but I dont get any error also.

Please Advice for this.

Comment: can you post code where you update the widget?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I'm having the same issue now.

Comment: Remove your many try-catches. Might be easier to figure out where the error actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck up with the same questions. Ultimately found out that alarm manager should not be used for more than a few hours. See this question for reference.

[android alarm manager stops after few hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146221/android-alarm-manager-stops-after-few-hours)