# android alarm manager stops after few hours

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I have create an alarm manager that start a service every 5 second, the app is running well but after few hours the alarm manager stop running. Note that the application is not used by the user which mean that it is running on background without user interaction. Does any one knows how to start a service every some second without stopping ?

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.TRUE); 
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 5), pi);
```

Comment: Man... put your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do such things with the alarm manager. The alarm manager is more 
a concept for tasks that should be done for a period of hours (in best cases).

If you need a precise processing of your tasks, use a handler inside
of a service, that post executes your runnable. 
Inside of your runnable, call the method to post execute the runnable again.

Save the runnable and handler as member variables of the service and make
the process sticky. If you want to stop the service and handler (handler won't
stop if you just call stopService(Context) or Service.stopSelf(), you need
to call removeCallbacks(runnable) with your runnable on the handler.

Cheers.

**Btw**: Think about if you really really want to start a service every 5 seconds.
Maybe just do the Service work inside of the runnable of the service 
I just described.

**Edit2**: If you need the Service to be reliable, add a BroadcastReceiver for Boot Actions, that will receive the Broadcast at boot and restart your service.

**Edit3**: Code to check if your service is running, without starting it:

```
    public static boolean isRunning(Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (YourService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

BUT, nevertheless, check in onStartCommand that your member 'handler' isn't null
and ignore a start request if so, because this could lead you to a situation with multiple runnable processing.

**Edit4:**

*Service Code Snippet:*

```
public class LoopingServiceSnipped extends Service{

public static final long STANDARD_FREQUENCY = 1000;
private static       long         loopingFrequency         = STANDARD_FREQUENCY;
private Handler  serviceHandler; 
private Runnable loop; 

//EXTRAS

private static final String       INTENT_EXTRA_STOP_SERVICE  = LoopingServiceSnipped.class.getSimpleName() + "_INTENT_EXTRA_STOP_SERVICE";
private static final String       INTENT_EXTRA_FREQUENCY     = LoopingServiceSnipped.class.getSimpleName() + "_INTENT_EXTRA_FREQUENCY";

/**
 * Determines if the service is running (reliably) without starting it.
 *
 * @param context
 *         needed for SystemServices
 *
 * @return true if the service is running
 */
public static boolean isRunning(Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (LoadingScreenAppDetectionService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void stopService(Context c) {
    Intent i = new Intent(c, LoopingServiceSnipped 
    i.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_STOP_SERVICE, true);
    c.startService(i);
 }

public static synchronized void setFrequency(Context c, long frequency) {
    Intent i = new Intent(c, LoadingScreenAppDetectionService.class);
    i.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_FREQUENCY, frequency);
    c.startService(i);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    init();
}

private void init() {
    //do your initialization here
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (shouldStopService(intent)){
        LOG.d("Going to stop service!");
        tryStopService();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    } else {
        return startOrContinueService(intent);
    }
}

private void tryStopService() {
    stopLooping();
    stopSelf();
}

private void stopLooping() {
    if (serviceHandler != null){
        serviceHandler.removeCallbacks(getLoop());
        serviceHandler = null;
    }
}

private int startOrContinueService(Intent intent) {
    if (hasNewFrequency(intent)){
        setFrequency(intent);
        stopLooping();
    }
    if (!isServiceRunning()){
     startLooping();
        }
    } else {
        LOG.d("Going to continue with service!");
    }
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


private boolean hasNewFrequency(Intent intent) {
    return intent.hasExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_FREQUENCY);
}

private void setFrequency(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.hasExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_FREQUENCY)){
        loopingFrequency = intent.getLongExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_FREQUENCY, STANDARD_FREQUENCY);
    }
}

private boolean isServiceRunning() {
    return serviceHandler != null;
}

private boolean shouldStopService(Intent i) {
    if (i.hasExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_STOP_SERVICE)){
        return i.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_STOP_SERVICE, false);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private void startLooping() {
    if (serviceHandler == null){
        serviceHandler = new Handler();
    }
    serviceHandler.postDelayed(getAppDetectionLoop(), getFrequency());
}

private Runnable getLoop() {
    if (loop == null){
        loop = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //do your looping work here
                startLooping();
            }
        };
    }
    return loop;
}
```

Additionally add Boot Receiver and Screen TurnOn Receiver.

Comment: Thank you, do you think that the handler you describe will not stop anymore even when the app is killed and not running for a lot of time ??

Comment: So you mean that i will start the service one time on MainActivity and the handler will work every 5 second without stopping?

Comment: Thats why you make the Service sticky. (return sticks in 'OnStartCommand method). A sticky service will be started again, once it died. To be absolutely sure, add the boot receiver and a receiver for the screen turning on and check if your service is still running.

Comment: I can check if the service will still running because i have a toast displayed every 5 second :D i will test it . Hope that the garbage collector of android or the memory does not kill this handler after few days...

Comment: Once in a while, it will be killed. For sure. But it will be started soon again.

Comment: Okay.. can you estimate the world "Soon" in minutes, hours or day ?? :D

Comment: I have a Service like this built myself and ...it runs about hours but gets killed like once a day and starts himself afterwards again. :)

Comment: Yes, basically it runs forever and gets interrupted once in a while for some minutes.

Comment: Great thank you a lot Jack. i will test it my self and calculate the exactly time when the service is stopped and when it will run again and i will post that here maybe it can be helpful for someone :) can you put your own code

Comment: No problem :) I can add some more code if you want, but maybe not until the weekend. See u later.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, had to work at the weekend, too. Will add it today.

Comment: i liked this approach of runnable and service, but is this still valid nowdays? since Android has some perfomance improvements, is this secure? i mean, ```a service that has a handle with loop postDelayed to start a task``` or i should continue using a ```Alarm to start the service and start the task when start service```?

Comment: It depends on how often/frequently you want to start the "task" that should be done. If it is as often as in this question, like every five second, I would still use this approach. If you need your task only like every hour, I would use the alarm manager to start a service that does the task once and reschedules itself.